# SSRS filter on integer value with default so all data is returned if blank

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2008-r2

SSRS (underlying SQL server is 2008 R2) filter on integer value with default so all data is returned if blank

For SSRS, VS-2015, I want to filter on an integer value but have it return all data if this is left blank by the user.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure why there is a downvote....

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216005/ssrs-adding-a-default-blank-to-parameter-properties

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (if you have a small number of potential integer values) is to use "available values" (forming a dropdown) and then match on them as if they were strings.  I'm sure there is a more general way to do this (so if someone has any ideas please post), but this is one way to do this.